# can't use bigInteger constructor for primes

Tags: kotlin

i'm working in kotlin, and need to generate a really big prime.

So i'm looking at the Biginteger constructor for prime's. Here from the documentation (https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/BigInteger.html) :

```
BigInteger(int bitLength, int certainty, Random rnd)
```

So I write this code:

```
import java.math.BigInteger
import kotlin.random.Random
fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    val rng =  Random(42)
    val field = BigInteger(9734,1,rng)
}
```

However, kotlin can't find this constructor. I can still use the other constructors from Biginteger

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using a bad `Random`. The constructor of `BigDecimal` uses `java.util.Random`, not `kotlin.random.Random`.